# Issue with Breaking a Method Android

Tags: android, loops, methods, media-player, break

Below code dose not break the method or loop but instead it loops the music forever. When `(n==maxCount)` it should change the value of `n=1` and come out of OnCompletionListener, ie.,the music should stop play, this is what i want.

how can i fix this ?

```
    protected void playsound() {
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            if (n<=maxCount) {
                mp.start();
                n++;
                if(n==maxCount){
                    n=1;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    mp.start();
```

maxCount value depends on Spinner value and `n=1` is declared globally.

Below is the corrected code it works perfectly, is there any mistake in below code? because some user said that  "With this code you are running the danger of missing the exit condition, because if n == maxCount as you enter, then n > maxCount after you n++. In short, it'll run until you hit maxint, then it'll crash"
 ?

```
protected void playsound() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            if (n<=maxCount) {
                mp.start();
                n++;
                if(n==maxCount){
                    n=1;
                    mp.pause();
                    mp.seekTo(0);

                }
            }
        }
    });
    mp.start();
}
```

Comment: What is the the initial value of maxcout

Comment: initial value of maxcout = 2.

Comment: With the latest edit, you run the danger of missing the exit condition, because if `n == maxCount` as you enter, then `n > maxCount` after you `n++`. In short, it'll run until you hit `maxint`, then it'll crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

You can't stop the music with `mp.start();` you need to use `mp.stop()` instead

---

You are checking  `if (n<maxCount) {`

And inside the same condition you are checking `n==maxCount`, How in the world value less than a number equal to that number, i.e `n==maxCount` will never meet
so you need to change the condition like this

```
if(n<=maxCount)
```

> Below code dose not break the method or loop but instead it loops the music forever

Yes because your return statement will never satisfy n==maxCount

Comment: In all fairness: the OP is incrementing `n` between the two conditions. Hence, if `maxCount == (n-1)` at the first condition, it would be `maxCount == n` at the second.

Comment: @MH. He edited his question...and changed the condition, check recent edits of him 1 min ago

Comment: @SaiKiran If you want to stop the music then you need to call mp.stop() instead of mp.start(), as you are calling mp.start() every time so that music wil not stop

Comment: @Pragnani I removed `return;` and added `mp.pause(); mp.seekTo(0);` it works perfectly, is it ok? and @323go said "With the latest edit, you run the danger of missing the exit condition, because if n == maxCount as you enter, then n > maxCount after you n++. In short, it'll run until you hit maxint, then it'll crash." what dose he mean ?

Comment: @SaiKiran what he meant was if somehow somewhere else in your program n gets set to maxCount, then `n<=maxCount` will be true, n will get set to maxCount+1, and then `n==maxCount` will be false so n will never get set back to 1, and `n==maxCount` will never be true. You could change `n==maxCount` to `n>=maxCount` and that'll ensure that n will always be set back to 1 when it needs to be

Answer (score 1):

The problem is where you run `mp.start()`.  Move it to an else like so:

```
if (n<maxCount) {
    n++;
    if(n==maxCount){
        // Don't play the sound anymore.
        n=1;
        return;
    } else {
        // Continue playing the sound.
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

The problem you have is you check for `if(n==maxCount)`, but you play the sound either way, and then you reset n to 1 so it will keep playing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put `mp.start()` after the inner if. Since you start the music every time, it will always come back to `onCompletion`, where it is able to be started again even after maxCount plays, because you're setting `n=1;`

```
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        if (n < maxCount) {
            n++;
            if(n == maxCount){
                n = 1;
                return;
            }
            mp.start();
        }
    }
```